# Why did Ray Kroc's past haunt him in The Founder?

Tags: character, the-founder

It seems like every time he went to a bank or went to a social event, people mentioned kitchen beds, cups and other things.  I don't recall the movie really getting into it, but was he a pitchman or something?  I mean, I know he sold mixers but I don't put a multi-mixer in the same category as laughable products. 
 They kept saying his face looked familiar, but there couldn't have been infomercials back in the early 50's.  Where would they have seen him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They kept saying his face looked familiar, but there couldn't have been infomercials back in the early 50's. Where would they have seen him?

### They'd met him before...

..presumably when he pitched other proposals that obviously they did not lend him money for.

Recall, he was selling the multi-mixers **on commission**...he didn't own the company that made them. He was always looking for something of his own.

[**Script**](http://twcguilds.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/THE-FOUNDER_Script_wCover_Rd12.pdf)

> **LOAN OFFICER**
>
> You look familiar. Have we met?
>
> **RAY KROC** (a drop uneasy)
>
> I don’t believe so.
>
> **ON LOAN OFFICER**, staring, **determined to place the face**. He
>   snaps his fingers--
>
> "The Fold-A-Nook! (hint of smirk) “It’s Like A Murphy Bed... For Your
>   Kitchen!”

and

> **LOAN OFFICER #2**
>
> Have we met?
>
> The man **searches his face**. Kroc squirms.
>
> **LOAN OFFICER #2** (CONT’D)
>
> The paper-cup guy.

The implication seems clear... Kroc had approached these loan officers before for funding for other projects that they considered less worthy of funding.

It seems also that they remember him because of the somewhat *unusual* products he was proposing...since they recall him as "that [insert product] guy". Since they think he's always shopping a loser they don't fund this new proposal either.